# I want my function to return a table that contains the numbers inside the #

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following error :

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, fnToken Procedure, Line 24
> Invalid object name 'dbo.fnToken'.

I tried returning all the numbers ..

```
select dbo.fnToken('#254#251451#')
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnToken
(   
@Token varchar(100)
)
RETURNS @Listenum TABLE(num varchar(50))
AS
begin
declare @compt int
declare @num varchar(50)
set @compt = 1
while  SUBSTRING(@token,@compt,1)<>''
    begin
        if SUBSTRING(@Token,@compt+1,@compt)<>'#'
            begin
                set @num= @num+SUBSTRING(@Token,@compt+1,1)
                set @compt=@compt+1
            end
        else 
            begin
                Insert  into @Listenum(num) values(@num)
                
            end 
    end 
Return (SELECT num FROM @Listenum)

ENd
```

This is the expected output :

> 254
>
> 251451

Comment: Can't you just `REPLACE()` them? For the error just fix your `select dbo.fnToken('#254#251451#')` you don't specify what to select from `dbo.fnToken`

Comment: i want to return the numbers inside that token with a table function

Comment: What version you have @YounesHarir?

Comment: I am a Sql server 2008R2 user  So i guess those functions wont work for me ,

Comment: 2008R2 has 5 days of support left, @YounesHarir, you should really look at updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT  value
  FROM  STRING_SPLIT('#254#251451#', '#')
 WHERE  TRIM(value) <> '';
```

Depending on your version of SQL-Server its a built in function.  If your on an older version have a look at string split functions on here.  There are plenty of options.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a Table-Value Function like a Scalar Function. But this is a really bad way of splitting values out of a delimited value as it's iterative. Use an [XML Splitter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108499/3484879), [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) or `STRING_SPLIT` (if you're on SQL Server 2016+).

If you're using STRING_SPLIT the correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT SS.[value] AS num
FROM STRING_SPLIT(''#254#251451#','#') SS
WHERE SS.[value] != '';
```

The same syntax would be true for `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`, if you're not on SQL Server 2016+.

*Edit: Op is using an old (and about to be completely unsupported) version of SQL Server, so they will need to use [`DelimitedSplit8k`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Hope to help, my friend :))

I added more @separator param, you can remove it by fixing "#" value.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnToken
(   
@stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @separator nchar(1)
)
RETURNS @Listenum TABLE(num varchar(50))
AS
begin
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@separator, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@separator, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @Listenum 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @Listenum
 SELECT @stringToSplit
Return

ENd 


SELECT num 
FROM dbo.fnToken('#254#251451#', '#')
WHERE TRIM(num) <>''
```